# Make react player fit entire container

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I have a video player component that uses react-player library with a container div around it to determine its size. When the video displays, there is a small margin on the left and right side of it between the edges of its container. Does anyone know how I can get rid of these margins?

Here is what the video looks like in the app
[image]

Here is the react

```
  const playerComponent = (
<div className="h-64 sm:h-96 bg-blue-300 flex justify-center rounded-lg overflow-hidden">
  <ReactPlayer
    height="100%"
    width="100%"
    playing={true}
    controls
    url={currentMediaURL}
  />
</div>
```

);

Comment: What if you get rid of the borders or padding ?  I only know normal CSS but conceptially you could try :
padding:0px;
margin:0px;

or if it ends up being a border element, border:0px; or border;none; or something like that might help?  We need to see more CSS code, as its probably a nesting situation.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set below CSS property.

`margin:0px, padding:0px`

This will remove any padding/margin to componens.

Answer (score 0):

Added 'aspect-video' to the parent container. 2ez.